# Netbeans CRUD generator: customization and is it efficient for real applications?

Tags: jsf, named-query, netbeans-7.2

I use netbeans 7.2.1. Is JSF CRUD Generated code efficient for real applications? 
I have created a test database and used netbeans CRUD generator. It uses `DataModel` and `PaginationHelper` instead of Lists for CRUD operations. There is an Entity `Test.java`, a `TestFacade.java` and `TestController.java`. and jsf files `list.xhtml`, `edit.xhtml`, `view.xhtml`, `create.xhtml`. I added a `NemdQuery` to entity file:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Test.findByTestCriteria", query = "SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE t.testCriteria = true")
public class Test implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue    
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "testCrieteria")
    private boolean testCrieteria; 

public Test() {
}

//Getters and Setters
```

And created the query in TestFacade.java:

```
@Stateless
public class TestFacade extends AbstractFacade<Test> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public TestFacade() {
    super(Test.class);
}

public List<Test> testCriteria(){
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Test.findByTestCriteria",Test.class);        
    return q.getResultList();
}    
}
```

And I have added a method in TestController.java to retrieve testCriteria Query:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testController")
@SessionScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

    private Test current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    private DataModel testCriteria = null;
    @EJB
    private com.test.TestFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public Test getSelected() {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new Test();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return current;
}

public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
    if (pagination == null) {
        pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
            @Override
            public int getItemsCount() {
                return getFacade().count();
            }

            @Override
            public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
            }
        };
    }
    return pagination;
}

public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;
}
public String prepareList() {
    recreateModel();
    return "List";
}

public String prepareView() {
    current = (Test) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "View";
}
//getting testCriteria items
public DataModel getTestCriteria(){                
    if(items == null){
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    testCriteria = new ListDataModel(ejbFacade.testCriteria());         
    return testCriteria;        
}
//custom view page
public String viewTest(){
    current = (Test) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "ViewTest?faces-redirect=true";
}
//custom viewTestCriteria
public String viewTestCriteria(){
    current = (Test) getTestCriteria ().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "ViewTest?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

And Retrieving testCriteria in a `p:dataGrid` in index.xhtml:

```
<h:form>
                        <p:dataGrid value="#{testController.testCriteria()}" var="item" columns="4">                                
                            <p:column>
                                <h:panelGrid columns="1">                                                                                
                                    <h:commandLink id="viewTestCriteria" value="#{item.title}" action="#{testController.viewTestCriteria()}"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataGrid>
                    </h:form>
```

With this code all testCriteria data are there in index.xhtml but when I click the commadnButton to view them they all show the first Item. It seems that in the `DataGrid` it doesn't get the `selected` item. And if I refresh the List.xhtml which contains all test data, and then coming back to index.xhtml and pressing commandLink it throws a NoRowAvailable exception.

I hope I have stated my question clearly and I would appreciate any guide because I am new to this technology.

Update:
After googling and research for two days and thinking I thought of using `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item.id}" target="#{testController.selected.id}">` and `<f:param name="#{testController.selected.id}" value="#{item.id}">` but it didn't work.

Update:
So far I'm almost confident that no row is getting selected so the data grid returns first row. But I'm still not sure how to modify `viewTestCriteria()` to set the `current` item and `selectedItemIndex` correctly.

Comment: Hi, using netbeans 8.2 I still have the same problem, could you fix this ?